# How do I give RPM/WPM permissions to a Handle without OPENPROCESS?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to Read and Write Process memory. With this program I have to type in the PID every time. I want this to be automated so I used FindWindow to get the window of "Dummy" and return a handle. But that handle doesn't have RPM/WPM permissions. Any ideas what to do?

```
DWORD PID = 0;
int Read = 0;
uintptr_t pRead;
bool flag;
cout << "Enter PID of Process: " << endl;
cin >> PID;
cout << "Enter Address to Read " << endl;
cin >> hex >> pRead;

HANDLE fProcess = FindWindow(NULL, "Dummy");

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
if (hProcess == NULL)
{
    cout << "Something went wrong. Getting last Error." << GetLastError() << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

flag = ReadProcessMemory(fProcess, (LPCVOID)pRead, &Read, sizeof(Read), NULL);
```

Comment: Why do you think that the solution is not to use OpenProcess?

Comment: Because I don't want to use OpenProcess?

Comment: How are you going to obtain a process handle without using `OpenProcess`? This isn't a smorgasbord where you get a free choice on how to do things. You have to adhere to the API. `OpenProcess` is the way to obtain a process handle to an existing process.

Comment: Anyway, moving on, `FindWindow` returns an `HWND` rather than a `HANDLE`. You don't check whether or not that function call succeeds. In any case, `ReadProcessMemory` expects a process handle and not a window handle. So it's a mistake to pass a window handle to `ReadProcessMemory`. You ask if you can avoid calling `OpenProcess`, but the irony is that your code calls `OpenProcess` and then does nothing at all with the process handle that is returned.

Comment: Even furthermore, why are you calling `CloseHandle` when `hProcess` is null? That will just lead to another error, not that you actually check for it. When `OpenProcess` returns null, that means it has failed and you don't have a process handle. You only need to close the process handle if it succeeds and returns a process handle. You do that after you have finished using it in `ReadProcessMemory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindWindow` returns a window handle, which incidentally should be declared as `HWND`. `OpenProcess` returns a process handle. `ReadProcessMemory` expects to be passed a process handle.

You pass the window handle to `ReadProcessMemory` rather than the process handle. `ReadProcessMemory` will therefore fail and report that the handle is not valid. Pass `hProcess` to `ReadProcessMemory`.

If you are going to ask the user for the PID, then you don't need a window handle, and you can remove the call to `FindWindow`. If you want to obtain the PID from a window handle use `FindWindow` to obtain a window handle, and then call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to obtain the process ID.

Comment: Oh, I thought I could pass a FindWindow handle to RPM. Got it. Never mind my question then. Thanks.

Comment: You need to take good care when reading the docs. For RPM it states "A handle to the process"